# Sums with squares of binomial coefficients multiplied by a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

It has long been known that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{m} \binom{m}{n}^{2} = \binom{2m}{m}.
\end{align}
What is being asked here are the closed forms for the binomial series
\begin{align}
S_{1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{m} \left( n^{2} - \frac{m \, n}{2} - \frac{m}{8} \right) \binom{m}{n}^{2} \\
S_{2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{m} n(n+1) \binom{m}{n}^{2} \\
S_{3} &= \sum_{n=0}^{m} (n+2)^{2} \binom{m}{n}^{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{n}^2
&=\sum_{n=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{n}\binom{m}{m-n}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{m-k}{n-k}\binom{m}{m-n}\tag{2}\\
&=\binom{m}{k}\binom{2m-k}{m-k}\tag{3}\\
&=\binom{m}{k}\binom{2m-k}{m}\tag{4}\\
&=\binom{2m-k}{k}\binom{2m-2k}{m-k}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{n}=\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{m-n}$
$(2)$: $\binom{n\vphantom{k}}{k}\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{n}=\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{k}\binom{m-k}{n-k}$
$(3)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)$\vphantom{\binom{k}{n}}$
$(4)$: $\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{n}=\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{m-n}$
$(5)$: $\binom{n\vphantom{k}}{k}\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{n}=\binom{m\vphantom{k}}{k}\binom{m-k}{n-k}$

---

Apply the Lemma to
$$
\color{#C00000}{n^2}-\frac{m}2\color{#00A000}{n}-\frac{m}8\color{#0000FF}{1}=\color{#C00000}{2\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}}-\frac{m}2\color{#00A000}{\binom{n}{1}}-\frac{m}8\color{#0000FF}{\binom{n}{0}}
$$
and
$$
n(n+1)=2\binom{n}{2}+2\binom{n}{1}
$$
and
$$
(n+2)^2=2\binom{n}{2}+5\binom{n}{1}+4\binom{n}{0}
$$

Comment: The Lemma provided yields the results desired, namely: \begin{align} S_{1} &= \frac{1}{4(m-1)} \binom{2m-2}{m-2} \\ S_{2} &= 2 (m^{2} + 2m -1) \binom{2m-3}{m-2} \\ S_{3} &= \frac{2}{m} \, (m^{3} + 8 m^{2} + 12 m - 8) \binom{2m-3}{m-2} \end{align}.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle n\binom mn=m\binom{m-1}{n-1},$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^mn\binom mn^2=m\sum_{n=0}^m\binom mn\binom{m-1}{n-1}=m\binom{2m-1}m$

comparing the coefficient of $x^{2m-1}$ in $(1+x)^m(1+x)^{m-1}=(1+x)^{2m-1}$

Comment: I think the last expression should be $m{{2m-1}\choose m}$.

Comment: @Slade, Thanks for your feedback